# Displaying default image

Tags: php, mysql

I have a default image set in the db in the column default_image. If the default_image = 1 I want it to display the default image and if default_image = 0 I want text to say no image available. 
How do I make sure only the default image is displayed. Here is what I am doing now and it just displays any image that has the same link_id.

the column media_link is the address to the image.

```
<?php if (!empty($row['default_image'])){
echo "<a href='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'><img src='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'/></a>"; 
}
else{
    echo "<div align=\"center\">No image available</div>";
}?>
```

What do I do to make default_image "1" in the database display and nothing else? Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is another piece of code to show all the images for that link_id

```
if ($row['media_link']){
echo "<a href='http://localhost/t_images".$row['media_link']."'><img src='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."' /></a>"; 
}
else{
    echo "<div align=\"center\">No images available</div>";
}
}
```

there is 6 images for this current id
When i echo the vardump on this page the correct image has this
string(1) "1"
while the other 5 images "non default"
show this string(1) "0"
I am not sure how to show only the correct default image where it goes on the page in my first code.
Does this info help at all?

EDIT AGAIN/FIXED:
I fixed it by adding ORDER BY default_image DESC to the end of my query. Don't know if that is the best thing to do but if anyone has any other suggestions i would be glad to hear them. Thanks everyone for all your help. You all gave great answers but in the end I just added the order by statement to my query and it works that way so I am happy.
Thanks!

Comment: If you echo out `$row['default_image']` what does it give you? Or better, use `vardump()` to get its type, too.

Comment: Make sure $row['default_image'] is number 0 not string "0".

Comment: var_dump give me this string(1) "0"

Comment: var_dump result shows your database has default_image value is 0. try setting it to 1 in db for checking

Comment: it is set to 0 on purpose from when images are uploaded. an image with the value one 1 is considered default. i just cannot figure out how to display it.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, `$row['default_image']` is a string. Of course, PHP is not a strongly typed language, but it still has to figure out what you mean. In your example, you are expecting this:

```
empty("0") === true
```

which does not happen. The empty string `""` is empty, the number `0` is empty, but the string `"0"` is not. Instead you could use either of:

```
$row['default_image'] !== "0"
  // Uses strict comparison, which might not be what you expect
0+$row['default_image'] != 0
  // Uses casting, which might fail if the string doesn't contain a number
$row['default_image'] != "0" || !empty(0+$row['default_image'])
  // Uses short-circuiting, and should cover all (most) cases
```

There are other variants. Myself, I am not sure which I would choose between them: it depends on what you mean, exactly.

Comment: That does not work either I am beginning to think my problem is somewhere else possibly.

Comment: I am guessing maybe it does not know which picture to use, there is multiple images but just one of every gallery has default_image set to 1 and that is the one that needs to be showed.

Comment: Which one does not work? I made a few modifications to 2 and 3 because of afterthoughts, did they help?

Comment: I cannot get either to work and the 3rd one gives this error unexpected T_LNUMBER. I am going to make an edit above and post more info please look at my edit when i post here in a minute.

Comment: $row['default_image'] != "1" makes 1 of the 6 images show but not the default and when i change the default it does not change. I am not sure it knows what image to choose from $row['media_link'] but I figured if it was matched to the default number like i am trying that it would display.

Answer (score 1):

Check Default_image against 1 instead of empty.
try: ..

```
<?php
if( isset($row['default_image']) && $row['default_image'] == 1){
echo "<a href='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'><img src='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'/></a>"; 
}else{
    echo "<div align=\"center\">No image available</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
<?php if (!empty($row['default_image']) && $row['default_image'] == 1){
         echo "<a href='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'>
               <img src='http://localhost/images".$row['media_link']."'/></a>"; 
      }
      else{
         echo "<div align=\"center\">No image available</div>";
      }?>
```

Comment: I get the no image available with both of these answers.

Comment: do one thing write echo var_dump($row['default_image']); to know exactly what is coming in that var and write condition accordingly.

if $row['default_image'] is string then you need to write condition like this $row['default_image'] == "1".

Comment: that means value is 0 ant its length is 1. so according to your logic it will execute else part and it is executing else part. your code is working as expected.